# Open GL rotation: view "jumps" where rotating more than 90 degress

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I am using the following code to perfom yaw/pitch rotation:

```
- (void)rotateCameraUsingYaw:(double)yaw andPitch:(double)pitch
{
    GLKVector3 centerToEyeVec = [self centerToEyeVec];
    GLKVector3 rightVector = GLKVector3Normalize(GLKVector3Normalize(GLKVector3CrossProduct(centerToEyeVec, self.up)));

    GLKMatrix4 yawRotationMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeRotation(yaw, self.up.x, self.up.y, self.up.z);
    GLKMatrix4 pitchRotationMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeRotation(pitch, rightVector.x, rightVector.y, rightVector.z);
    GLKMatrix4 yawPitchRotationMat = GLKMatrix4Multiply(yawRotationMatrix, pitchRotationMatrix);

    GLKVector3 newCenterToEyeVec = GLKMatrix4MultiplyVector3(yawPitchRotationMat, centerToEyeVec);

    self.eye = GLKVector3Add(self.center, newCenterToEyeVec);

    [self recalculateUpVector];
}
```

This code works well as long at pitch value is lower than PI / 2. When pitch gets to PI / 2 the model is rotated (up vector is rotated). I am no sure why it happens.

Comment: Are you rotating the camera around his own axis?

Comment: I am rotating the camera around its up and right axes

Comment: what means "jumps"? model jumping slightly or it's rotates to another direction?